# あるメソッドがコールされると紐づけたラムダ式内部を実行したい（別メソッドへ通知）

Tags: c#, unity3d

■現状
　PhotonCloudというマルチオンラインのしくみを使って
　マルチ対戦を作ろうとしています。
　
　PhotonEventManager.csのOnConnectedToPhotonは
　PhotonServerに接続されるとイベントが飛んできます。
　イベントが飛んで来た時に、ある処理が呼ばれるという仕組みを作りたいのですが
　呼ばれずに悩んでおります。
　OnConnectedToPhotonメソッドが呼ばれることは確認できています。
　イベントやデリゲートなどの基本的な事でできると思うのですができていません。

■やりたい事（C#3.0）
　タイトルのラムダ式にこだわっているわけではなく、
　あるメソッドが呼ばれたことを別のメソッドに通知するというような事が
　したいというのが意図になります。

■ソースと説明
　下記、PhotonEventManager.csのOnConnectedToPhotonと
　ConnectionPhase.csのSetManagerメソッド内でラムダ式内部が呼ばれるように
　紐づけているつもりなのですが、OnConnectedToPhotonメソッドが呼ばれますが
　ラムダ式内部は呼ばれないです。

●PhotonCloud.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class PhotonEventManager : Photon.MonoBehaviour {

    /// <summary>
    /// 接続成功時に呼び出される。
    /// </summary>
    public void OnConnectedToPhoton()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnConnectedToPhoton");
    }

    //接続が切断されたときにコール
    public void OnDisconnectedFromPhoton()
    {
        Debug.Log("Disconnected from Photon.");
    }
}
```

●ConnectionPhase.cs

```
using System;

public class ConnectionPhase
{

    public void SetManager(PhotonEventManager manager)
    {

        manager.OnConnectedPhoton = () => 
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Success");
        };
    }
}
```

■環境
Unity5.5.1f1
C#3.0
VisualStudio 2015 Community

Answer (score 3):

`OnConnectedToPhoton()`が呼ばれたときに実行する処理を`PhotonEventManager`の外部から登録できるようにしたい、と解釈しました。

`PhotonEventManager`クラスの中で

```
public delegate void Action();       //////// 下のActionが未定義だと怒られるようなら追加(クラス外に書いても可)

public event Action PhotonConnected; //////// 追加

/// <summary>
/// 接続成功時に呼び出される。
/// </summary>
public void OnConnectedToPhoton()
{
    Debug.Log("OnConnectedToPhoton");

    //////// 以下追加
    Action action = PhotonConnected;
    if(action != null)
        action();
}
```

のようにイベント定義とそのハンドラを呼び出すコードを追加します。

登録する側は

```
    manager.PhotonConnected += () =>
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Success");
    };
```

のようにイベントハンドラを登録すればOKです。

Comment: 的外れなことを書いてしまっていたところを修正しました。

Comment: ＞的外れなことを書いてしまっていたところを修正しました。　UnityはMonoを使っている関係でC#のバージョンが低いもので、伝え下手ですいません。

Comment: まだ試せてなくてすいません、ご定時いただいたやり方でやってみます。